# Operation Rejected By Operating System

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, twilio, whatsapp

I am trying to write a Script to send Messages Periodically from NodeJS using Twilio on Android via Termux Emulator. When I try to Install the Twilio Library using
`npm i twilio@3.30.0` in the project it Shows `EPERM` warning multiple times and then shows and Error stating :
`The Operation we Rejected by your Operating System`

Is there a Fix to This Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the machine worked for me.

And check your anti virus

And if nothing work, do `npm login`